# Install Node.Js in a Sonarqube instance on the docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, sonarqube

so I'm trying to launch SonarQube on the docker through `docker-compose`. This is my `.yml` file:

```
version: "3"


services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "5432:5432"
    links:
      - db:db
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=postgres
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
#     - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube_new/data
     - ...../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
     - ....../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
     - POSTGRES_DB=sonar
    volumes:
     - .../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data:/var/lib/postgresql
     # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
     - ..../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Everything boots up and works kind of correctly. Then I'm lauching the analysis of the project and get this error:

```
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
ERROR: Failed to parse Node.js version, got 'Couldn't find the Node.js binary. Ensure you have Node.js installed.
```

If this would be regular install, I'd just add NodeJs, but it's docker.

How should I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: I liked reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/a-better-way-to-develop-node-js-with-docker-cd29d3a0093) article...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for the answers, especially @leeman24, that is awesome insight how to deal with docker images.

Although the real solution turned out to be installing NodeJS on MY machine, not the scanner server machine. In other words, server is fine out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are pre-build images out there for SonarQube with NodeJS installed, you could make your own custom image. It would look something like below:

`./app/Dockerfile`

```
FROM sonarqube

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nodejs npm -y
USER sonarqube
```

```
version: "3"


services:
  sonarqube:
    build: ./app
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "5432:5432"
    links:
      - db:db
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=postgres
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
    volumes:
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
#     - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube_new/data
     - ...../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
     - ....../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
     - ..../Work/tools/_SonarQube_home/bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
     - POSTGRES_DB=sonar
    volumes:
     - .../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data:/var/lib/postgresql
     # This needs explicit mapping due to https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/4e48e3228a30763913ece952c611e5e9b95c8759/Dockerfile.template#L52
     - ..../Work/tools/_PostgreSQL_data/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

You could then build and startup the new images:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Test if node is installed:

```
docker-compose exec sonarqube node -v
docker-compose exec sonarqube npm -v
```

Comment: this is very useful. Thanks!