# How to add node.js to this docker-compose file that spins up SonarQube?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I've installed a local SonarQube server in Docker on my machine, using [this docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes/docker-compose-postgres-example.yml) based on [this recipe](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/master/recipes.md). It spins up a Postgres database backend as well as SonarQube itself.

When I run analysis of a Java project through Maven, it analyzes everything except my project's JS and CSS. I get these warnings:

```
CSS files were not analyzed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?

Some JavaScript rules were not executed. Error when running: 'node -v'. Is Node.js available during analysis?
```

SonarQube's [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/css/) explains: "In order to analyze CSS code, you need to have Node.js >= 8 installed on the machine running the scan. Set property `sonar.nodejs.executable` to an absolute path to Node.js executable, if standard node is not available."

My question for you Docker-Compose experts is: **How can I incorporate Node.js into the docker-compose configuration?** (So I can get the benefits of these analyses without having to install and configure Node.js on the host machine outside of Docker...)

Comment: Turns out someone else asked this question a short while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58950485/install-node-js-in-a-sonarqube-instance-on-the-docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At the same level as your compose file, create a `Dockerfile`

   - *Note1: For example simplicity, I'm building against the `latest` tag by default which is a bad practice for production. You should pick the [version that suits your needs](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube?tab=tags) (e.g. `lts`, `9.2.4-developer`....)*
   - *Note2: For sonarqube versions prior to 8, the official image was based on an ubuntu image. Since version 8, the base image has been switch to alpine. I kept the previous example `Dockerfile` below*

   `Dockerfile` for sonar >= 8

   ```
   FROM sonarqube

   USER root
   RUN apk --no-cache add nodejs
   USER sonarqube
   ```

   `Dockerfile` for sonar < 8 (for memory)

   ```
   FROM sonarqube

   USER root
   RUN apt-get update \
       && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs \
       && apt-get clean
   USER sonarqube
   ```
2. Modify your compose file to build and use this new image (note that the image name **must** change).

   ```yaml
     sonarqube:
       image: my_local_sonarqube
       build: .
       ports:
         - "9000:9000"
       networks:
         - sonarnet
       environment:
         - sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
       volumes:
         - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
         - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
         - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
   ```
3. Launch your app. The image will be built automatically since it does not exists. If you need to rebuild the image later (e.g. after a change to the `Dockerfile`), you need to either do it manually with `docker-compose build` or to use the `--build` option to `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Looks promising but I still get the same error.  In the stacktrace it says "`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`".  It may be that Maven (on the host machine) calls 'node' instead of the SonarQube server.

Comment: Well, it turns out I need node on my machine.  Your answer is a good one for how to add node to the sonarqube container, though.  I was able to test the running container with: `docker exec [container id] node -v` and it worked.

Comment: Right now, it doesn't work. sonarqube image wasn't based on ubuntu image.

Comment: That's right. The image is based on Alpine since sonar version 8. You can easily adapt the above using apk instead of apt. You might even propose an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Zeitounator Sorry, I don't have the solution now. [Here is my Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/pplmx/0e87c633ec7ddcfa5184e171c0a302c0) But node command cannot be found in container.

Comment: Your Dockerfile does not make any sense: you are installing nodejs in a virtual apk package and removing it on the next line. How do you expect your image to have node installed in such a case ? I just updated my answer to take ver >= 8 into account.